# Sending small text file in push notification FCM (android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a file which is stored in my phone I want to broad cast it to my clients through GCM or FCM.
Just wanted to know is there a way to send file in push notification using fire base or google cloud messaging.

Comment: Why down vote? hey people just wanted to know its possible or not. why can't you write in comment section .

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a huge payload (such as a file in your case) in a notification, however, in Firebase there is this facility to send out key-value pair data as a broadcast if that helps your cause.
[image: Advanced notification setting]

One other way around this is to send out a link in the notification as an extra payload (as I mentioned above) and from your app download the file from that URL... Firebase Storage can help you in that case.